# .splice() doesn't shorten my array completly

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have an array with Strings, if there is nothing written in the String I want to remove it from the array with `.splice()`.

Somehow it does not get all empty entries. If there are 2 empty entries in the beginning, it only gets one.

Here is my [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKcCU/) and code:

```
stringArray = ["", "", "Banana"];

console.log('before stringArray.length: ' + stringArray.length);

for (var i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    if (stringArray[i] === "") {
        stringArray.splice(i, 1);
        if (i > 0) i--;
    }
}

console.log('after stringArray.length: ' + stringArray.length);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to loop backwards, because every time you `splice`, the length and indexes change:

```
for (var i = stringArray.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if(stringArray[i] === ""){
        stringArray.splice(i, 1);   
    }
}
```

Alternate solution with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (documentation page provides a shim for old browsers that won't support this method):

```
stringArray = [ "","","Banana"]; 
var a = stringArray.filter(function(item) {
   return item !== '';
});
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, of course with looping backwards, is with a `while` loop:

```
var stringArray = ["", "", "", "Apple", "", "", "Banana", "", "", ""];

var i = stringArray.length;
while (i-- && (stringArray[i] !== "" || stringArray.splice(i, 1)));

console.log(stringArray);    // ["Apple", "Banana"]
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/VEmAV/

Comment: I like this, despite being hard to read. It could be even shorter if you replace `{ }` with a semicolon.

Comment: @bfavaretto Haha thanks. Yeah, hard to read is what I expected, didn't like, but works. It could obviously broken down into a normal `while` loop that's readable, but I was just trying to figure out a fun 1.5 liner. And good point, I always forget the `{}` isn't always required